# How do I create a block in a module that can be referenced via an entity reference field?

Tags: blocks, paragraphs, plugins

I'd like to be able to reference my programmed block as a field in a paragraphs.

I've

- Generated a module with drupal console - drupal generate:module
- Used the template for a block from the example module. Only has Plugin/Block/MyBlock.php

I create a new field in my paragraph

- Field type Reference
- choose other

How do I get the block to be able to be embedded in this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve this you may use the [Block field](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_field):
From module description:

> **Use Cases**
> Add blocks to a node's sidebar.
> Add blocks to paragraph.
> Create a carousel of content and configurable blocks.

1. install and enable the module
2. Create a new field of type **Block(plugin)** in your paragraph type
3. In case you want only your custom block to be referenced in the field settings uncheck all other blocks in the **AVAILABLE BLOCKS** config like this for my **Hello block** for exemple
   [image]
4. now you can reference your block in the paragraph.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. My block is now appearing in the block reference list but this is easier.